# PHP Fatal Error - Cannot unset string offsets

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I am trying to patch an issue with WP Plugin Contact Form 7 running on Google App Engine.

The patch code is:

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: Fix Contact Form 7
*/    
add_filter('wp_mail', 'fix_wp_mail_filter', 11);
function fix_wp_mail_filter($args) {
    unset($args['headers']['X-WPCF7-Content-Type']);    
    $new_wp_mail = array(
        'to'          => $args['to'],
        'subject'     => $args['subject'],
        'message'     => $args['message'],
        'headers'     => $args['headers'],
        'attachments' => $args['attachments'],
    );      
    return $new_wp_mail;
}
```

Now when I test the contact form I get a 500 error in browser and checking the App Engine request logs, shows this error:

**PHP Fatal error:**

> Cannot unset string offsets in /base/data/home/apps/s~aura-www/20170807t210800.403218500896707567/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/cf7_fix_plugin.php on line 8

Is there a problem with the PHP code?

Comment: What does `var_dump($args)` give you before trying to `unset` anything?

Comment: I'm not sure how to test this with my wordpress setup on App Engine. Could I add a line to this php plugin file to output this?

Comment: I'm not sure about the rest of your code and how and when this function is being called, but maybe adding `var_dump($args); die();` and making a request to a page that uses this plugin gives you something. Or if have better ways to do this, like dumping $args to a log file, or using other debug features that you might have available. But if there are no other options, try var_dump and die and let us know the output. I guess `$args['headers']` is probably a simple string and not an array.

Comment: Should I replace the unset function with this function, or place it below?

Comment: Place it before it, in a new line between `function fix_wp_...` and `unset(...)`

Comment: OK output was ...  array(5) { ["to"]=> string(26) "X@X.com.au" ["subject"]=> string(18) "X "test"" ["message"]=> string(121) "From: test Subject: test Message Body: test -- This e-mail was sent from a contact form on AURA Website" ["headers"]=> string(81) "From: AURA Website X-WPCF7-Content-Type: text/plain " ["attachments"]=> array(0) { } }  ... I have removed personal details with an "X"

Comment: What is you final goal? What do you want to do with this header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because `$args['headers']` is a string, not an array, thus the line`unset($args['headers']['X-WPCF7-Content-Type']);` raises this error. If you want to change it, use string manipulation functions like `str_replace`.